# What's wrong with this C program?I's always appear a new number we not input?Compiled with Dev-C++

Tags: c, dev-c++

[image]

### This program is used to sort numbers #### min to max

When I input `5 1 3 7 9 6 8 2 0 4`
the result is `0 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8`
the `9` disappeared and appeared another `3` that we did not input.
When I input `99 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11 0`
the result is `0 3 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88`
the `99` disappeared and appeared a `3` that we did not input. What's wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int b[]){
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<10-i;j++){
            if(b[j+1]<b[j]){
                int temp = 0;
                temp = b[j+1];
                b[j+1] = b[j];
                b[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }   
}

void main(){
    int a[10];
    printf("please enter numbers you want to sort:\n");
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("The number you have input were:");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    sort(a);
    printf("The sorted numbers are:");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some undefined behavior here: `b[j+1]` for `j=9` occurences you're accessing outside of the bounds (effectively `b[10]` which is the 11th element of `b`, but it contains only 10 elements) of your array.

When you have behavior like that, what'll happen is completly unpredictable. It may work. It may produce garbage values (like it did for you). On another try, your program might crash with a segfault.

Answer (score 2):

In certain instances `b[j + 1]` will be evaluated for `j = 9` (this happens when `i` is 0) and so you'll be accessing an element outside the bounds of the array.

The program behaviour on your doing that is *undefined*. (The "new element" you observe is possibly due to your introducing it by that out-of-bounds access).

Comment: Its worth noting that if OP tries again, any number of things may happen with that, including the program just taking an exit via segfault.

Comment: Yup. The compiler also reserves the right to eat your cat.

Comment: The compiler won't do anything funny, it doesn't even detect that. The OS however may just decide to eat your cat :p

Answer (score 0):

just remove **- i** in **for(int j = 0;j<10-i;j++)** in sorting

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int b[]){
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<10-i;j++){
            if(b[j+1]<b[j]){
                int temp = 0;
                temp = b[j+1];
                b[j+1] = b[j];
                b[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

change it to

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int b[]){
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<9;j++){ //just remove the i because it is useless. 
                                //change the maximum iteration to 10 to prevent out of bounds exception
            if(b[j+1]<b[j]){
                int temp = 0;
                temp = b[j+1];
                b[j+1] = b[j];
                b[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solved. Sorting numbers in reverse/forward order.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int b[]){
     int temp = 0;
     for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
          for(int j = 0;j<10-i-1;j++){
              if(b[j+1] > b[j]){
                 temp = b[j];
                 b[j] = b[j+1];
                 b[j+1] = temp;
              }  
          }
     }
 }

int main(){

    int a[10];
    printf("\nplease enter numbers you want to sort:\n");
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        scanf("%d ",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe number you have input were:");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }

   sort(a);

    printf("\nThe sorted numbers are:");
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
              printf("%d ",a[i]);
         }

return 0;
}
```

If you want to sort in forward order just change:

```
  b[j+1] > b[j] to b[j+1] < b[j]
```

Try it, It's working correct.